# Erro estranho em classe c++

Tags: c++

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class guns{
public:
    string name;
    int ammo;
    void reload(){
        ammo = pente;
    }
    void shoot(){
        ammo -= 1;
    }
private:
    int pente = ammo;
};
int main(){
guns fuzil;
fuzil.name = "M-16";
fuzil.ammo = 50;
cout << "O fuzil " << fuzil.name << " tem " << fuzil.ammo << endl;
fuzil.shoot();
fuzil.shoot();
cout << "ammo: " << fuzil.ammo << endl;
fuzil.reload();
cout << "carregado: " << fuzil.ammo;
}
```

A saída é:

```
O fuzil m16 tem 50
ammo: 48
carregado: 31
```

Porque quando reload() é executada 'ammo' tem o valor bizarro 31?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabalhe com [construtores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s16xw1a8.aspx), o problema é que quando você declarava a sua variável, ela se constrói sem valor pois você não tinha método construtor para tal. Quando fui compilar seu programa e debuguei `pente` ele me retornava 0.

Com a classe construtora você passa todos os atributos no momento do distanciamento da classe e já atribui a ela mesma, eu adicionei as seguintes linhas:

```
 guns(string _name,int _ammo)
:name(_name),ammo(_ammo),pente(_ammo){}
```

Nela, você está criando um construtor que pede uma string(name) e um int(ammo) e logo após, atribui a classe, sendo assim o valor do `pente` será atribuído logo após o valor de `ammo` ser atribuído também.
Segue o resultado final:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class guns{
public:

    guns(string _name,int _ammo):
    name(_name),ammo(_ammo),pente(_ammo){}

    string name;
    int ammo;
    void reload(){
        ammo = pente;
    }
    void shoot(){
        ammo -= 1;
    }
private:
    int pente = ammo;
};

int main(){
    guns fuzil("M-16",50);
    cout << "O fuzil " << fuzil.name << " tem " << fuzil.ammo << endl;
    fuzil.shoot();
    fuzil.shoot();
    cout << "ammo: " << fuzil.ammo << endl;
    fuzil.reload();
    cout << "carregado: " << fuzil.ammo;
}
```